# Python Turtle shows an error when window is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, turtle-graphics

I have an issue in python.
I'm making a small program called "Stars" with more than 29 lines in turtle graphics.
When I close the turtle window before the program has finished it show an error. That's not a big problem, but when I converted it to exe (with pyinstaller) and then closed the window before the program has finished, then an alert box pops up and says: "failed to execute script Stars".

[image: Error Image]

Is there a better way of ignoring this than putting every line in try-except?:

```
try:
   #each line of code
except:
   pass
```

Thanks in advance

When it helps: I'm in Python 3.7.7 and in windows 10

Here's the code:

```py
from turtle import *
shape("turtle")
width(2)
color("gold")
begin_fill()
for _ in range(5):
        forward(100)
        right(2 * 360/5)
        forward(100)
        left(360/5)
end_fill()
penup()
goto(0, 200)
write("STAR", font = ("Arial", 50), align = "center")
goto(-200, -200)
pendown()
stamp()
forward(50)
stamp()
forward(50)
stamp()
forward(50)
stamp()
forward(50)
stamp()
forward(50)
stamp()
forward(50)
stamp()
forward(50)
exitonclick()
```

And here's the pyinstaller command:

```sh
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --noconsole  "C:/Users/jeeva/Desktop/Tanmay_new/python/Python_turtle_answers/Stars.py"
```

Comment: I really recommend posting these 29 lines in order to get a feeling of what's going on

Comment: @Anwarvic Thank's for the suggestion. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that as you said by `try..except` block over the whole lines like so:

```
try:
    # all 29 lines of your code:
except:
    pass
```

And it will work just fine!

---

But, I really suggest arranging your program into different functions; like:

1. Function to create turtle:

   ```
   def create_turtle():
       shape("turtle")
       width(2)
       color("gold")
   ```
2. Function to draw and fill the star-shape:

   ```
   def draw_fill_star():
       begin_fill()
       for _ in range(5):
               forward(100)
               right(2 * 360/5)
               forward(100)
               left(360/5)
       end_fill()
   ```
3. Function to write the word "star":

   ```
   def write_start():
       penup()
       goto(0, 200)
       write("STAR", font = ("Arial", 50), align = "center")
   ```
4. Function to write the stamps:

   ```
   def write_stamps():
       goto(-200, -200)
       pendown()
       stamp()
       forward(50)
       stamp()
       forward(50)
       stamp()
       forward(50)
       stamp()
       forward(50)
       stamp()
       forward(50)
       stamp()
       forward(50)
       stamp()
       forward(50)
       exitonclick()
   ```
5. And finally, a function to execute them all.

   ```
   def execute():
       create_turtle()
       draw_fill_star()
       write_start()
       write_stamps()
   ```

And now, you can wrap the function into a `try...except` block like so:

```
try:
    execute()
except Terminator:
    print("Program has been terminated")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I never thought that you could put all lines of code in 1 try-except and not each line in a different one.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Thanks but can you explain me what except Terminator means?

Comment: It means you have terminated the program before it terminates by itself

Comment: @ Anwarvic Thank you very much